# Docker essentials: Why is `docker-compose pull` not enough? Why do I need `git pull` too?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, travis-ci

I have a problem where `push` (on dev) and `pull` (on production) via `docker-compose` is not enough and old stuff is presented by my Nginx web service. When I push and pull via Git too, everything works. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oups, I found it out. My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "2.1"
services:

…

  web:
    build:
      args:
        HTTP_PROXY: ${HTTP_PROXY}
        HTTPS_PROXY: ${HTTPS_PROXY}
        NO_PROXY: ${NO_PROXY}
      context:
        web
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: user/repo
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./status.txt:/opt/status.txt
      - ./web/sites-available/default:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
      - ./web/www:/var/www/html
      - ./dump:/opt/dump
```

As you can see, my web folder is taken from my local ./web/www folder and not from the image… :D